# How to redirect with a Oauth token return with FASTAPI?

Tags: python, jinja2, fastapi

I am contacting you because I am trying to make a redirection by recovering the token but unfortunately my protected service is not accessible because no token is recovered and I do not know why.

I tried to put the token in the cookie but without result.

Here is my code:

```
@app.post("/login", response_model=Token)
async def login_for_access_token(form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends(), db : Session = Depends(get_db), 
username: str = Form(...), password: str = Form(...)):
    #user = authenticate_user(db, form_data.username, form_data.password)
    user = authenticate_user(db, username, password)
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Incorrect username or password",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )
    access_token_expires = timedelta(minutes=ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)
    access_token = create_access_token(
        data={"sub": user.username}, expires_delta=access_token_expires
    )
    auth = {"access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer"}
    response = RedirectResponse(url='/licence/',status_code=HTTP_302_FOUND)
    response.set_cookie(key='access_token', value=access_token)
    return response

@app.get("/licence/")
def form_post(request: Request, auth: User = Depends(get_current_user)):
    result = "Type a number"
    return templates.TemplateResponse('home.html', context={'request': request, 'result': result})
```

Here is the code for get_current_user:

```
async def get_current_user(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme), db : Session = Depends(get_db)):
    credentials_exception = HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
        detail="Could not validate credentials",
        headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
    )
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
        username: str = payload.get("sub")
        if username is None:
            raise credentials_exception
        token_data = TokenData(username=username)
    except JWTError:
        raise credentials_exception
    user = crud.get_user_by_username(db, username=token_data.username)
    if user is None:
        raise credentials_exception
    return user
```

Here is my output: :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgAD4.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrIUm.png)